# Computing harmonic sum

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, gm.general-mathematics, sums-of-squares, differential-calculus

I want to show the following equalities for harmonic sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{2n}\frac{-3}{x^4}([x]-2[\frac{x}{2}])dx$$

Any idea?

Comment: do you know how to prove this identity?

Comment: This question is in the level of bachelor student and suitable for Math.StackExchange . But when I was bachelor student in 2007, I wrote a book about 400 problems in Mathematical Analysis I,II based on questions of Putnam competition and Mathematical monthly journal. see page 146 problem 38 here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-JKfzn6I35qd29adTFwTVZHMmM/view?usp=sharing (you can use google translate )